# Android camera issues

Tags: android, camera

Using the google developer tutorials and following them exactly and my app will just restart or completely shut down and not get the picture from the camera. I had the exact same code working about 30 minutes ago but now it wont work. All I did was try and implement a button. Any help is greatly appreciated.

HEre is my code. Its short and simple so hopefully someone can give some advice on where to go from here.

```
package com.example.camera;

import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.provider.MediaStore;
 import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageView iv;
Bitmap bitmap;
private static final int actionCode = 100;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
dispatchTakePictureIntent(actionCode);
}



protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 handleSmallCameraPhoto(data);
 }

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int actionCode) {
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
    }

private void handleSmallCameraPhoto(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
   iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
     }
```

Comment: are you getting any error messages? Can you put your log here

Comment: I am not getting any errors from the log cat  This is what is coming from the console ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.camera/.MainActivity }  Then this  ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

Comment: "All I did was try and implement a button"  I don't see any button code.

Comment: I took the button out to try and get it to work again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some times it does get messy to ask the android system to take images for you. I have a [Camera Library Project](https://github.com/girishnair12345/Girish-Camera-Library-Project) you can use the library to take the picture sample is also provided. or you can go through the code to understand it

Comment: Thanks for that library I appreciate it. Can I contact you if I have any problems with the code or more questions?